# MAC Address to IP Address?

Tags: router

I have a Belkin Universal Repeater that is behaving badly, so I factory reset the repeater.

My problem right now, I can't connect to the router web management page. This is most likely caused by invalid settings that I have. On the pre-reset setting, the router was set to 192.168.1.1, and from the user manual, the default is 192.168.2.254. I have tried changing my gateway address to either IP to no avail.

I do have information about the MAC address of the router. Is there a way to find out what is a router IP address from it's MAC address? I am currently wired to the router, but don't have any information about gateway (router) IP nor subnet mask used.

Another thing that can help is if anyone have any download link to the Belkin "Wireless Range Extender Management Utility". I have tried googling but no light yet. I seem to have misplaced the CD that comes with the package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the utility that will "find" the device (as well the information on IP address).

http://en-us-support.belkin.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/2866/~/f5d7132-wireless-g-universal-range-extender%2Faccess-point---management-utility

This device is a real pain to work with, avoid at all cost.

Answer (score 4):

What I've done in situations like that is to isolate the device and a computer on a single switch, then run Wireshark or the like to snoop what packets are being emitted by the device as it powers up.  Usually the device will look for a dhcp server or for a gateway of some kind, and you can figure out what its IP is from there.

Comment: That's probably a faster way to resolve the situation than my way!

Answer (score 2):

You could try pinging the broadcast address and see who responds.

`ping 192.168.1.255` or `ping 192.168.2.255`

You'll want to make sure you're in the right subnet from your workstation

Comment: Hmm... trying to ping 192.168.0.255 (my workstation and another working router is in that subnet) doesn't return anything. Does this work on Windows? :(

Comment: I don't believe a Windows ping will give you back a response by IP from whoever answers.  Maybe on another platform?

Comment: John: It does. (I have often used broadcast pings when trying to connect a mobile phone.) But not all devices _reply_ to those...

Comment: When you do this, look for replies in Wireshark.  You won't get results from the ping tool alone.

Answer (score 1):

If the device is reachable and responds to arp requests, then you can try to use "arp -a" in Windows to get a look at the ARP cache which maps your IP's to MAC addresses.  But the most sure fire way will likely be the Wireshark route from David.  Good luck!